# Address bar in android browser

Tags: java, android, address-bar

In my app there is a `webView` with default Website Google. I see in some apps on any webpage there is an address bar on top, So user can enter new website address any time. How can we do that?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question to be more suitable, what have you tried or what have you read?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496549/change-url-at-runtime-in-webview-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change URL at runtime in webview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496549/change-url-at-runtime-in-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Following is the bare minimum you need to do.Ofcourse you have to enhance as per your need.

activity_webview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     tools:context="com.carworkz.dearo.WebviewActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_web_address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textWebEditText"
    android:imeOptions="actionGo"
    android:hint="Enter Url" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

WebViewActivity.java

```
public class WebviewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText webAddressView;
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    webAddressView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_web_address);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webAddressView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                String url = webAddressView.getText().toString();
                if (!url.isEmpty())
                    webView.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```